# How can I pass the search result from elasticquent to a route in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

My question is based on how I can pass the $searchResult in my Controller class so as I can use it to display the search result

This is my Controller

```
class SearchController extends Controller {
    public function getHome($searchFor = null) {
      $result = SearchPost::all();
      return view('home', ['resulta' => $result]);
   }

   public function postSearch(Request $request) {
      $this->validate($request, [
        'searchString' => 'required|max:20|alpha',
      ]);

      $searchFor = $request['searchString'];
      //Connection with model(SearchPost) to search
      $searchResult = SearchPost::search($searchFor);

      return redirect()->route('home', ['searchFor' => $searchFor]);
   }
}
```

Routes:

```
Route::get('/{searchFor?}', [
  'uses' => 'SearchController@getHome',
  'as' => 'home'
]);

Route::post('/search', [
  'uses' => 'SearchController@postSearch',
  'as' => 'search'
]);
```

Comment: Are you facing any problem in this approach ?

Comment: I cant figure out how can I pass the search result so as I can send to the home route to display coz when someone such for something I should be able to display the result I have my view already but how can I use the $searchResult in home route am learning stage of laravel framework @jaysingkar

Answer (score 0):

Try the following methods:

```
return redirect(route('home', ['searchFor' => $searchFor]));
```

Or

```
return redirect('home')->with('home', ['searchFor' => $searchFor]);
```